# Cannot find lg2c

Tags: matlab, windows-vista, fortran, mex

I'm trying to create mex for matlab from some cpp and fortran files. They all compile well and creates the .obj file. But during linking I get the error lg2c not found.

I have matlab 2007 installed in win vista. I also have mingw and gnumex installed.
The mex -setup in matlab returns 2 compilers lcc and VS 2003

I'm using G77 fortran compiler
Followed instructions in http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~pcarbo/Compile_LBFGSB_on_Windows.txt

Comment: What Fortran compiler are you using ?

Comment: And can you find g2c on your system ?

Comment: I cannot find g2c in my system.

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.5. I read somewhere that g2c is not part of version 4 and higher. Is it possible to find an installer for gcc 3.4.5?

Comment: If you're using gcc 4.5 you should use gfortran instead of g77.

Comment: Where is the "fortran part" of the problem in here? As far as I can see, this is a problem with matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Fortran programs compiled with `g77` (as provided by GCC <= 3.4.6) need to link with libg2c. Fortran programs compiled with `gfortran` (as provided by GCC >= 4.0.0) need to link with libgfortran. In any case, the compiler driver (whether `g77` or `gfortran`) ought to do that for you.

Now, the question is: is there a reference to libg2c in the Matlab-provided files. If so, you have no choice but to provide libg2c. You can find a download [there](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/BaseSystem/GCC/Version3/).